# Using if-else in "with" statement in Python

Tags: python

I want to open a file that may be gzipped or not. To open the file, I use either

```
with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
    some_func(f) # arbitrary function
```

or

```
import gzip
with gzip.open(myfile, 'r') as f:
    some_func(f)
```

I want to check if `myfile` has a `gz` extension or not, and then from there decide which `with` statement to use. Here's what I have:

```
# myfile_gzipped is a Boolean variable that tells me whether it's gzipped or not
if myfile_gzipped:
    with gzip.open(myfile, 'rb') as f:
       some_func(f)
else:
    with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
       some_func(f)
```

How should I go about it, without having to repeat `some_func(f)`?

Comment: you can try `with gzip.open() if is_gzip else open() as f:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if myfile_gzipped:
    f = gzip.open(myfile, 'rb')
else:
    f = open(myfile, 'r')
with f:
    some_func(f)
```

The result of `open` and `gzip.open` is a context manager. `with` invokes the entry and exit methods on context managers. There is nothing special in calling those functions inside the `with` statement itself.

Comment: @irene No.  The `with` statement still does that for you.

Comment: oops I deleted my comment. For posterity, reposting it: "This requires me to add an `f.close()` statement, right?" To which the answer is "no". Thank you @JohnGordon!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to put `open` and `with` on the same line.

You can open the file as one step, and then do `with f` later.

```
if myfile_gzipped:
    f = gzip.open(myfile, 'rb')
else:
    f = open(myfile, 'r')

with f:
   some_func(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

I find that `ExitStack`s can be helpful in these cases:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

with ExitStack() as stack:
    if myfile_gzipped:
        f = stack.enter_context(gzip.open(myfile, 'rb'))
    else:
        f = stack.enter_context(open(myfile, 'r'))
    some_func(f)
```

Comment: It is not necessary in this case. `ExitStack` solves a different problem, when you want to have an _unknown_ number of nested contexts. In OP's case, there is always exactly one context (though we don't know which, ahead of time), so IMO `ExitStack` is an overkill. Still good to know about, to be sure!

Comment: @Amadan Yeah, most definitely overkill. Paranoid me kinda likes that it immediately enters the context. In the other approaches, say you add logic in the between initialization and the `with` statement (like logging what option you chose, etc). It's possible an exception raises from that logic and you skip entering the `with` statement. Although, that could be refactored in later when actually needed 

Comment: That is a fair argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ternary operator to evaluate two different expressions based on a condition:

```
with gzip.open(myfile, 'rb') if myfile_gzipped else open(myfile, 'r') as f:
    some_func(f)
```